# User settings to store customer settings or quotas in clean architecture context

Tags: node.js, postgresql, database-design, clean-architecture

For an application with clean architecture and NestJs I want to store customer settings or quotas. I have modules `customer`, `text-generator` and `module-b`. I want to describe settings for each. In module `text-generator` I want `usage_limit` and in `module_b` `text_color`.

How can I map this multiple setting to `customer` without coupling my module?

I use PostgreSQL but can use MongoDB in the worst case. I tried the "settings bag" pattern but don't know how to map settings tables to `customer` without a lot of many-to-many tables.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: What is stopping you? In what context? [ask] [Help] PS What exactly do you mean by "setting bag pattern"?